# Android: Can't get registration ID for android device 4.1.1 returns "java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

For this one phone running android 4.1.1(huawei y300-0151) I cannot get the `registration ID`. However, for my nexus 4 and note 2 I receive a registration id.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
```

On this line = > `regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);`
it returns "java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"... what does this mean.

Also what is weird is that only on this phone in the method below in Google Play Manager, the if statement `(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)` causes a system warning, invalid int="" .

```
public boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.mainScreenActivity);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,
                    this.mainScreenActivity,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.i("tag", "This device is not supported.");
            mainScreenActivity.finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

### EDIT!!!!! - > I found this information on the android website

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html

```
public static final String ERROR_SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

The device can't read the response, or there was a `500/503` from the server that can be retried later. The application should use exponential back off and retry.

### Constant Value: "SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE"

Any suggestions would help, I have double checked all of the permissions / obvious code and it does work for most devices.

Thanks, Ryan

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Google Play Services are active on this phone

Comment: hey i just checked that and it is, and we also just updated it as well to the newest version